# Is erasing and inserting in a single linked list thread safe?

Tags: c++, linked-list, thread-safety, singly-linked-list

Using std::forward_list are there any data races when erasing **and** inserting?  For example I have one thread that does nothing but add new elements at the end of the list, and I have another thread that walks the (same) list and can erase elements from it.

From what I know of linked lists, each element holds a pointer to the next element, so if I erase the last element, at the same time that I am inserting a new element, would this cause a data race or do these containers work differently (or do they handle that possibility)?

If it is a data race, is there a (simple and fast) way to avoid this?  (Note: The thread that inserts is the most speed critical of the two.)

Comment: If you have to ask, a good rule of thumb is: No, it's not thread safe. Actually, scratch the first part, that's always a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Does the standard make any guarantees regarding thread safety? If not then it's not good to rely on it, even if it works on your compiler today.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, the standard does make thread safety guarantees for the containers. They are fairly weak, though, and they are not sufficient to cover the user case in the question (see also my answer).

Comment: If you have `C++11` available (for `std::atomic` it's relatively easy to write a container that is safe for single producer/single consumer (see: https://github.com/chadkler/hipoconcon/blob/master/inc/ringbuffer.h) for a free-to-use (but not wholly vetted/tested) example.  It's not a `list`, but a `bounded ring buffer`.  Make sure `initial_size` is a power of 2.

Comment: @Chad I am using C++11, and I have considered some atomic options with spin locks.

Comment: The example above doesn't provide any spinning on its own, just simple boolean returns indicating success or failure, leaving the caller free to spin (or sleep, or yield) as appropriate.

Comment: Come on man, this is SO, don't you know that you're supposed to use Boost???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are thread-safety guarantees for the standard C++ library containers but they tend not to be of the kind people would consider thread-safety guarantees (that is, however, an error of people expecting the wrong thing). The thread-safety guarantees of standard library containers are roughly (the relevant section 17.6.5.9 [res.on.data.races]):

1. You can have as many readers of a container as you want. What exactly qualifies as *reader* is a bit subtly but roughly amounts to users of `const` member functions plus using a few non-`const` members to only read the data (the thread safety of the read data isn't any of the containers concern, i.e., 23.2.2 [container.requirements.dataraces] specifies that the elements can be changed without the containers introducing data races).
2. If there is one writer of a container, there shall be no other readers or writes of the container in another thread.

That is, reading one end of a container and writing the other end is *not* thread safe! In fact, even if the actual container changes don't affect the reader immediately, you *always* need synchronization of some form when communicating a piece of data from one thread to another thread. That is, even if you can guarantee that the consumer doesn't `erase()` the node the producer currently `insert()`s, there would be a data race.

Comment: The documentation says that its safe to access any of the elements while inserting and erasing (assuming its not the element you are erasing) because it does not modify them in any way (in fact, all iterators to all the other elements are still valid).  Its only my specific use case that I cannot find solid information about.

Comment: @latreides: if your implementation makes guarantees beyond those I stated above, it is free to do so. However, concurrent access and modification (as in changing the number or location of objects) to any of the standard library containers may introduce data races. 23.2.2 [container.requirements.dataraces] may be what you refer to: you can change _elements_ stored in a container without the container introducing data races (note, that you still need to make sure that the element access is race free).

Answer (score 3):

No, neither `forward_list` nor any other STL containers are thread-safe for writes. You must provide synchronization so that no other threads read or write to the container while a write is occurring. Only simultaneous reads are safe.

The simplest way to do this is to use a mutex to lock access to the container while an insert is occurring. Doing this in a portable way requires C++ 11 ([std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)) or platform-specific features ([mutexes in Windows](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), perhaps [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) in Linux/Unix).

Comment: mutexes in Windows (which doesnt use futexes) are too slow for this use case.  The documentation says that the std::list and std::forward_list are thread safe for nearly every operation, (for example you can erase from the list, and access any other element of the list, without a data race) but I cannot find information about this specific case.

Comment: @latreides You must assume it is not safe.

Comment: @latreides Without looking at the standard, if I had to guess, I'd say that due to iterator invalidation rules for `forward_list` *nearly* every case would be thread-safe except for the one you're concerned about. So you'll have to resort to providing synchronization. If you don't care about portability, you could use a `CRITICAL_SECTION` (assuming this is not a multi-process scenario). These are pretty lightweight unless there is actual contention.

Comment: I posted this question so I could stop assuming.  I am trying to find out for certain so I can plan accordingly.

Comment: @latreides Then stop assuming... it is *not* safe because the documentation does not specifically say it is. That's how it works. Unless you want to look at the implementation of the containers, but then you're making assumptions about the implementation and not relying on the interface contract.

Comment: @latreides - OK, then use a Critical Section.

Comment: @Praetorian It definitely must be portable, and this is what I thought too, but because I could not find any place that actually stated that its not safe, I asked to be sure.  I need to find a solution, one that does not involve expensive locking.  Its not important that the element get added at the end, and the "walk through" always iterates from beginning to end (and I can restart the walkthrough if needed), so there may be some trick I could do with atomics.

Comment: @MartinJames the last time I used various locking mechanisms, it was very expensive even uncontended, I do not wish to repeat this if I can avoid it.  If the process takes too long, then it will eliminate the reason for this code entirely (which is to take a time consuming task, put it on a list for another thread to deal with 'whenever').

Comment: Waht do you mean by 'time-consuming'?  10us not worth threading off.  10ms well worth threading off and the uncontended lock-time is not remotely significant.  The only way I can see lock time being an issue with a task of reasonable length is if you take a long time to push the objects onto the container, ie. you are pushing wide data instead of a pointer of some kind.  If you are doing that, stop doing it:)

Comment: @MartinJames for example, on Windows (not on Linux or Mac) an uncontested mutex in this particular situation, dropped performance by nearly half.  (It was hardly noticeable on Linux and Mac)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a version of the STL that explicitly states it is thread-safe then no, the containers are not thread safe.

It's rare to make general purpose containers thread safe by default, as it imposses a performance hit on users who don't require thread safe access to the container, and this is by far the normal usage pattern.

If thread safety is an issue for you then you'll need to surround your code with locks, or use a data structure that is designed specifically designed for multi threaded access.

Comment: Is there an std::forward_list-like container (that is part of the standard) that is specifically designed for multi-thread access?

Answer (score 1):

std containers are not meant to be thread safe.

You should carefully protect them for modify operations.

Comment: Not entirely correct, standard library containers are thread-safe for concurrent read access. It's only when you modify a container that you must provide external synchronization.

Comment: but if you protect the modify operation, then the read access must be protected.

Comment: @StephaneRolland with an std::forward_list read access is safe even if the container is modified so long as you use iterators and not indices.  For this container specifically, all iterators except the one(s) specifically modified/erased/etc... remain valid even after a container modification.